# asp.net / javascript: How to open a link in a new web page set to a width 640px and height 480px?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Morning All,

I was hoping someone could help or provide some sample code for me in refe to the following.  I not too sure if i can simply set the asp.net (Visual Studio 2010) properties or if i need some java script to complete my task.

I have a web page with a link on it that when users click it opens to a new web page via the _Blank command.

What i would like to do is have this page open on a really small scale (640px X 480px) and layerd on top of the main webpage.  This small page essentially just holds a gridview with items listed for documentation.

I have looked around the internet as i think this would be best done by using JavaScript in the smaller web page but i cant get this to work successfully.

I have found a sample and need to try and tweak this but have been unsuccessfull.

Here is the sample code i have....

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        var w = window.open("about:blank", "main", "width=640,height=480", true)
        window.opener = "main";
        window.open("", "_parent", "");
        w.opener.close();
    }
    </script>
```

My smaller web page is named uploadview.aspx

Any help is advenace is much appriechiated.

Regards
Betty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got to specify window URL in first param of window.open, and must have button to invoke that JavaScript, it's not clear why do you do that on page load event. Anyway, here is the example to open window on some link click

```
  <a href="#" onclick="OpenUploadView()">Open Upload View</a>
  <script type="text/javascript">

    function OpenUploadView() {
      window.open("uploadview.aspx?param=1", "_blank", "width=640,height=480", true);
    }

  </script>
```

You can also pass parameters to that aspx page like shown above.

Comment: Many Thanks, that worked a treat.  not overly familiar with Javascript, but this does the job.   Regards Betty.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window.opendialog()
For more visit https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.openDialog